# Blazor app sending wrong value to function inside loop

Tags: c#, blazor

I've been working on a Blazor app but I cannot seem to figure this out.

I'm trying to page a large data set with something like this:

```
<nav aria-label="">
     <ul class="pagination">
         ...
                
        @for (var i = PaginationInfo.StartNavigationPage; 
                  i <= PaginationInfo.StopNavigationPage;
                  i++)
        {
              <li class="page-item"
                        @onclick="(async () => ChangePages(i))">
                  <a class="page-link @PaginationInfo.ClassByPageNumber(i)"
                     href="/journal/@i">@i</a>
              </li>
         }
                
        ...
      </ul>
   </nav>
```

When I call ChangePages(i) it always uses the last value of i + 1.

On to my question, I understand the reason for this Blazor is using the saved state of `i`. Because the value of `i` is always 1 number higher that `StopNavigationPage`, how can I pass in the correct value for `i`?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine yes this did answer my question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `i` is a referenced variable which has a scope above the code blocks inside the for loop.

You need to set a scoped variable and use that as a parameter for your method calls.

This will solve your issue:

```
<nav aria-label="">
    <ul class="pagination">
        @for (
            var i = PaginationInfo.StartNavigationPage;
            i <= PaginationInfo.StopNavigationPage;
            i++
        )
        {
            var pageNumber = i; //Scoped Variable
            var className = PaginationInfo.ClassByPageNumber(pageNumber);
            <li class="page-item" @onclick="(async () => await ChangePages(pageNumber))">
                <a class="page-link @className" href="/journal/@pageNumber">
                    @pageNumber
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use `@onclick="() => ChangePages(pageNumber)"`, saves 1 state-machine.

Answer (score -1):

Create an attribute on `li` element with the value of `i` and when `ChangePages`  will be invoked just read the attribute and do your action.